# Data Not getting Added to JSON using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, arraylist

After thorough research I have not been able to find the solution of a simple problem of appending an object to my JSON.

```
{
"menu": {
    "parentmenu1": {
    },
    "parentmenu1": {
        "pm_name": "iceberg 98 ",
        "pm_time": "icebeest-98"
    }
},
"projectname": "project1",
"place": "gzb",
"firstlogo": "flogo",
"logo": "logo",
"colordirection": "TopLeft",
"color1": "color1",
"color2": "color2",
"fontcolor": "fontcolor"
```

}

And my PHP code looks like this

```
<?php

$parentmenu="Sixty";
$childmenu= "hell";
  $grandchildmenu= "icebeest";

  $parentmenu1="PUSH Approach-98";
  $childmenu1= "iceberg 98 ";
  $grandchildmenu1= "icebeest-98";
  $data = file_get_contents('format.json');

  $json_arr = json_decode($data, true);



  //$json_arr['menu']=array($parentmenu2);
  $parentarray = array('pm_name'=>$childmenu1, 'pm_time'=>$grandchildmenu1);
  echo $parentarray['pm_name'];
  $json_arr['menu']['parentmenu1'] = $parentarray;
  //array_push($json_arr['menu'], $parentarray);

  file_put_contents('results_new.json', json_encode($json_arr));
 ?>
```

The **parentmenu1**  gets removed as soon as I re-run the code.
But if I try adding the 2 arrays at once in same file, then it will add.
So please let me find out the way in which I can add data with key to the end of the structure. TIA

Comment: Please provide code directly in your question, not as a link or external source (as those can change/vanish over time).

Comment: And do not post it as image

Comment: I have provided the code. Please check now

Comment: @Mehdi The OP corrected it, but the correction was reverted by another user attempting to include the images in the question (instead of just linking to them). So it was probably just a mix-up with edits.

Comment: @navnav The OP is the one who approved the bad edit actually